# Is it bad to create symbolic links from appdata and programfiles in windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, 64-bit, symbolic-link

I have a ssd, and the space is running low, so i'd like to create a symlink from `C:\Program Files`, `C:\Program Files (x86)` and `C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData` to `D:\Program Files`, `D:\Program Files (x86)` and `D:\Users\Gabriel\AppData` respectively. Can it slow my system down or cause any kind of trouble for me? I already have a symlink at some `AppData` subfolders, will i have to delete the links for them or i can just create the symlink to `AppData` folder directly and the subfolders will continue to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is bad.

Can it slow down your system? Well, even though it will, that is not your problem. The problem is that after you do this, windows does not work correctly anymore. On Windows 7 you can move program files, but on windows 8, it will give errors.